# Queue search with different groups suggestion

Tags: java

Well basically I am making some kind of a "game search" where people are able to search a game in groups, lets say that there can be 5 people at max in one group and when game is found u are playing 5v5 game, tho groups could have less than 5 players.

So what I thought I can do, is to make an Queue object which would contain a list of all group objects that search a game, and then loop through that list and find and combine right groups together, but i feel like its going to be a mess using a list, because I will have to account a swell for stuff like elo of the players and match groups which are similar etc. which would result into many loops as far as i was thinking how to make it.

Would this be a viable solution? Or should I use some other structure for handling groups and searching?

Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: What is the "elo" of a player?

Comment: @OmarKooheji its the same as "rating", it shows how good player is

Comment: I think you might need to think about this problem a little more, you will need to sit down and design some heuristic for matching players. Expect to have multiple passes through your data to group players and assign them to balanced teams. If you can figure out how to do this well then there are many in the game industry who will want to have a word with you, because it's not an easy problem to solve unless your heuristics are pretty simplistic.

Comment: @OmarKooheji yeah, definitely i will have to think more about it, my structures arent that complicated but it has some complexity, i just wanted to know if any1 has any idea or something that would help.

Comment: Creating a good matchmaking algorithm is complicated. It sounds like you might need to define your problem a little more precisely than you already have.  See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/trueskill-ranking-system/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Ftrueskill%2F for an interesting description of how microsoft has dealt with matchmaking for xbox live.  Also, Elo is designed for 1v1 competition and doesn't necessarily work well for team games.  There's a lot of literature about this, I would probably do some reading before trying to imlement anything